# Dynamic background based on a timer (linear layout), how to?

Tags: android, dynamic, android-layout, timer, background

Hi I'm kind of beginner to android OS programming, and I got stuck with a problem, I cant figure out how to do a dynamic background, based on timers (say each 10 seconds a background changes to a different one) I have some code but it comes up with error, here's a sample:

```
private static final long GET_DATA_INTERVAL = 10000;
int images[] = {R.drawable.smothie1,R.drawable.omletherb1};
int index = 0;
ImageView img;
Handler hand = new Handler();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout layout= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearView1);
    hand.postDelayed(run, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);
}

Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        layout.setBackgroundResource(LinearView1).getDrawable(images[index++]);
        if (index == images.length)
            index = 0;
        hand.postDelayed(run, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);
```

Any help would be greatly apprieciated :D thanks

**EDIT**: The errors I get are on this line:

```
layout.setBackgroundResource(LinearView1).getDrawable(images[index++]);
```

It says that:

-layout cannot be resolved

-the method getDrawable(int) is undefined for the type Object

---

This error:

```
layout.setBackgroundResource(LinearView1).getDrawable(images[index++]);
```

It says that:

-layout cannot be resolved

-the method getDrawable(int) is undefined for the type Object

Please help :)

Comment: read below please :D I put it as an aswer as, this doesnt seem to accept code ;)

Comment: @Albert: if you have extra information to add to your question, please edit your question instead of adding an answer.  What you've added isn't an 'answer' because it doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Yeah true, I'm new to this site and I'm still learning to use it :)

Comment: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408920/dynamic-background-on-linearlayout-what-is-my-error/7408971#comment-8953318/%20%22Link%20to%20an%20answer%20to%20this%20thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally worked it out, after removing a few errors I have came up with this (and its working) :

public class CookBookActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
private static final long GET_DATA_INTERVAL = 1000;
int images[] = {R.drawable.omletherb1,R.drawable.smothie1};
int index = 0;
LinearLayout img;
Handler hand = new Handler();
private LinearLayout layout;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
    layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.main);
    hand.postDelayed(run, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);

    Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/BPreplay.otf");
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv2.setTypeface(tf2);


    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/BPreplay.otf");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);


    Button mainNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextScreen1);
    mainNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("com.unKnown.cookbook", "com.unKnown.cookbook.screen1");
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}

Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        layout.setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(index++));
        if (index == images.length)
            index = 0;
        hand.postDelayed(run, GET_DATA_INTERVAL);

    }
};

protected Drawable getDrawable(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return getResources().getDrawable(images[i%2]);
}
```

}